# How to return a Union type from a GraphQL Mutation

Tags: graphql-ruby

I want to use this pattern for returning validation failures from the GraphQL Ruby: https://medium.com/@sachee/200-ok-error-handling-in-graphql-7ec869aec9bc

From my mutation I'd like to be able to return a payload that is a union like this:

```
    class RegistrationPayloadType < Base::Union
      possible_types UserType, ValidationFailureType

      def self.resolve_type(object, context)
        if context.current_user.present?
          UserType
        else
          ValidationFailureType
        end
      end
    end
```

And my resolve method in the mutation is something like this;

```
      def resolve(input:)
        @input = input.to_h

        if registration.save
          candidate
        else
          registration.errors
        end
      end
```

The client can then call the mutation thus;

```
  mutation UserRegistrationMutation($input: UserRegistrationInput!) {
    userRegistration(input: $input) {
      __typename
      ... on User {
        id
      }
      ... on ValidationFailure {
        path
        message
      }
    }
  }
```

How in GraphQL-ruby can I return a Union as a payload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this was actually really simple. If you want to return a different type from the mutation, in my case the RegistrationPayloadType above.

```
    class RegistrationMutation < Base::Mutation
      argument :input, Inputs::RegistrationInputType, required: true

      payload_type RegistrationPayloadType

      ...
    end
```

Using the payload_type class method got me what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

This blog(https://www.abhaynikam.me/posts/polymorphic-types-with-graphql-ruby/) covers how you could use union types in GraphQL-ruby for polymorphic types. Here, instead of using `payload_type` another field Type is returned which resolves the union types.